# Condensing repeating jquery code for selector1, selector2 etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

I have eight clickable icons (pulse1, pulse2 - pulse 8) which are linked to the corresponding content (content1, content2 etc). Instead of writing the code below out each time for each is there a way I can condense it down using an increasing integer or something? Fairly new to this game!

Dev version can be seen at http://aceresponsive.webdevspace.co.uk

Many thanks.

```
$("#pulse1").click(function () {

  $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if ($('.purple-content').is(':visible')) {

       if ($('#content1').is(':visible')) {

           $(".purple-content").fadeOut();


       } else {

           $(".purple-content").fadeOut();

           $("#content1").fadeToggle();
       }

    } else {

       $("#content1").fadeToggle();

    }
});
```

which calls for:

```
<div class="purple-content" id="content1">
<h2>the brain</h2>

<img src="assets/img/icons/brain-dark.png" width="144" height="167" alt="The Brain"      class="alignright">
<p>Stroke … A serious medical condition that occurs when the blood supply to part of the brain is cut off. It can affect our bodily functions, thought processing, ability to learn, communication and emotions.</p>

<h3>Learn More</h3>

<ul>
 <li><a href="#">The factors that can increase risk</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Stroke symptoms</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Types of stroke</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: can you give an example of the html that makes up one of these sections and how how it relates to another section?

Comment: give your links and content areas a common class, give each content area an ID that actually represents the content in some way (not content1,content2, etc), then give your links an `href="#theid"` Now you can get the id for the content area from the link's href and show it, then hide the rest.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've added a link to the dev version and what the pulse links to... Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the HTML with some kind of reference, here I've given it an `data-` attribute which you can collect upon click with jQuery's `.data()` method.

```
<div class="pulse" data-contentref="1"><div>
<div class="pulse" data-contentref="2"><div>
..
<div class="pulse" data-contentref="n"><div>

<script>  
    $(".pulse").click(function () {

      var $Content = $('#content'+ $(this).data('contentref') +'');
      $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($('.purple-content').is(':visible')) {
           if ( $Content.is(':visible')) {
               $(".purple-content").fadeOut();
           } else {
               $(".purple-content").fadeOut();
               $Content.fadeToggle();
           }
        } else {
           $Content.fadeToggle();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Fiddle** added: http://jsfiddle.net/7JvFZ/3/

Comment: Thanks, does the corresponding data-contentref need be attached to both the button (#pulse) and the content? Tried it but can't seem to get it to work!

Comment: I've added a fiddle to give you an idea on how to work with Classes and `.data()` ids =) http://jsfiddle.net/7JvFZ/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize the function, assuming the ID numbers at the end of `pulse` never go into double digits:

```
$("[id^=pulse]").click(function () {
    var idNum = this.id.substr(this.id.length - 1, 1);
    $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if ($('.purple-content').is(':visible')) {
        if ($('#content' + idNum).is(':visible')) {
           $(".purple-content").fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(".purple-content").fadeOut();
           $("#content" + idNum).fadeToggle();
        }
    } else {
        $("#content" + idNum).fadeToggle();
    }
});
```